# How to open the second link in the adjacent tab?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

I have been trying many functions to open a link in a tab I recently opened but it does not work.

Minimum reproducible example with commentary saying what happens after each line (this is using Selenium webdriver, Java):

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com") //opens twitter in tab 1(intended)

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('https://google.com')"); //opens new tab (tab 2) then opens google.com(intended)
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.location.replace('https://facebook.com')"); //opens facebook.com in tab 1 (unintended)
```

I want Facebook to open in tab 2 instead.

Comment: Well... `window.location.replace` replaces location in current tab

Comment: same result, tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open `https://twitter.com` as the base url and then open `https://google.com` in the adjascent [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324). Next open the url `https://facebook.com` in the same adjascent [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780691/selenium-webdriver-hungs-or-stucks-while-switching-from-child-window-to-parent/44782329#44782329) you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for [numberOfWindowsToBe(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455402/how-to-handle-mutliple-windows-in-selenium-webdriver-need-to-switch-from-second/45459457#45459457) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://twitter.com");
          String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://google.com');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
          for(String child_window:allWindows)
              if(!parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_window))
                  driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
          driver.get("https://facebook.com");
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```